# By W&R's type theory, has Russell abandoned his view in his Principles §7?

Tags: foundations

[The Principles. §7](http://fair-use.org/bertrand-russell/the-principles-of-mathematics/s7#s7p1) :

> Thus, for example, the proposition "x and y are numbers implies $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ " still holds equally if for x and y we substitute Socrates and Plato[2]: both hypothesis and consequent, in this case, will be false, but the implication will still be true. Thus in every proposition of pure mathematics, when fully stated, the variables have an absolutely unrestricted field: any conceivable entity may be substituted for any one of our variables without impairing the truth of our proposition.

By W&R's type theory, a number is a class of classes while *Socrates* and *Plato* are individuals. If we substitute *Socrates* and *Plato* for x and y, both the hypothesis and the consequent will be nonsense. E.g., $\alpha \not\in \alpha $ is neither true nor false: it is nonsense. And if $a$ is an individual, $\lambda$ is a class of classes, then $a\not\in\lambda$ is also nonsense. Thus, both "Socrates and Plato are numbers," and "$(Socrates + Plato)^2 = Socrates^2 + 2Socrates  Plato + Plato^2$" are nonsense.

When $\phi \supset \psi$ is asserted, neither $\phi$ nor $\psi$ needs to be true, but both has to be significant. Thus, the variables in $\phi$ and $\psi$ must be restricted within their own types. The last sentence of §7 states that "the variables have an absolutely unrestricted field." I think W&R must have abandoned this view by the time they finished *Principia*. Russell's introduction to the 2nd ed of *The Principles* didn't point this out, please let me know if I am mistaken at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right : Russell's view *before* the developmen of the Type thoery as a solution to the paradoxes was exactly that the logic was a sort of "science of everything", i.e. a set of laws so general to be applicable to absolutely "everything".

Thus, the "individual" variables of what we called today *predicate logic* must range on every *object* whatever : human beings, numbers, etc.

See e.g. :

- Gregory Landini, [Russell's Hidden Substitutional Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=lE9P3fDjTYgC&pg=PA31) (1998), page 31.

Comment: The 8th paragraph of _Introduction to 2nd ed_ vaguely touched this point: "I come next to a more serious matter, .... my present point is that the absence of non-logical constants, though a necessary condition for the mathematical character of a proposition, is not a sufficient condition." He then took as an example "there are at least three things in the world." In pure logical form, and if the universe does not exit, variables in the bottom three types cannot be logically proved. I'm only disappointed by his stopping short from saying "nonsense" or "not significant."